# SharePoint Custom Button ListViewWebPart header

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

What would be the smartest way of adding a button next to the other: "New, Transfer, Share"?

Is there a location where you can create a custom action? Or do I need to override via JSLink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it for now at least. My code is a bit hardcoded, but I will sort it.
I added a "mutationobserver" to spot if the OOTB button "Share" gets disabled or enabled. 
If enabled, only one item is selected. 
Then I do additional checks in JSOM to see how many items that are selected, depending on that I show and hide certain buttons with JQUERY.

```
window.SIMON = window.SIMON || {};
window.SIMON.Library = {
editFunction: function () {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var item = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx)[0];
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(ctx));
    ctx.load(list, 'DefaultEditFormUrl');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        var editFormUrl = list.get_defaultEditFormUrl() + "?ID=" + item.id;
        openInDialog(800, 600, false, true, false, editFormUrl);



    }, function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });





},

displayFunction: function () {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var item = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx)[0];
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(ctx));
    ctx.load(list, 'DefaultDisplayFormUrl');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        var viewFormUrl = list.get_defaultDisplayFormUrl() + "?ID=" + item.id;
        openInDialog(800, 600, false, true, false, viewFormUrl);



    }, function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });





},
 PostRender: function (ctx) {


        if (!$('#QCB1_Button4').length > 0) {
            $('#QCB1 > ul.ms-qcb-zone.ms-qcb-leftzone').append(
                '<li class="ms-qcb-item"><button class="ms-qcb-button ms-qcb-buttons-alignmentfix js-listview-qcbShareButton js-callout-body js-qcb-button    ms-disabled"'
                + 'onclick="javascript:initShare();" disabled="disabled" type="button" title="Bjud in personer till markerade dokument eller mappar." id="QCB1_Button4" role="button" aira-expanded="false">'
                + '<span class="ms-qcb-glyph ms-listview-glyph-withmargin ms-core-form-heading    ms-disabled">&#xE078;</span>Dela flera<span class="ms-qcb-glyph "></span></button></li>');
            $('#QCB1 > ul.ms-qcb-zone.ms-qcb-leftzone').append(
                '<li class="ms-qcb-item"><button class="ms-qcb-button ms-qcb-buttons-alignmentfix js-listview-qcbShareButton js-callout-body js-qcb-button    ms-disabled"'
                + 'onclick="javascript:window.SIMON.Library.editFunction();" disabled="disabled" type="button" title="Bjud in personer till markerade dokument eller mappar." id="QCB1_Button5" role="button" aira-expanded="false">'
                + '<span class="ms-disabled"><img class="ms-disabled" border="0" alt="redigera" src="/_layouts/15/images/edititem.gif?rev=43" style="opacity: 0.3; width: 17px; vertical-align: bottom;"></span> Redigera<span class="ms-qcb-glyph "></span></button></li>');

            $('#QCB1 > ul.ms-qcb-zone.ms-qcb-leftzone').append(
               '<li class="ms-qcb-item"><button class="ms-qcb-button ms-qcb-buttons-alignmentfix js-listview-qcbShareButton js-callout-body js-qcb-button    ms-disabled"'
               + 'onclick="javascript:window.SIMON.Library.displayFunction();" disabled="disabled" type="button" title="Bjud in personer till markerade dokument eller mappar." id="QCB1_Button6" role="button" aira-expanded="false">'
               + '<span class="ms-disabled"><span class="icon viewicon" style="opacity: 0.3; width: 17px; vertical-align: bottom;"></span></span> Visa<span class="ms-qcb-glyph "></span></button></li>');


            var input = $('#QCB1_Button3');
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
                for (var i = 0, mutation; mutation = mutations[i]; i++) {
                    if (mutation.attributeName == 'disabled') {
                        if (SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(new SP.ClientContext.get_current()).length > 1) {
                            $('#QCB1_Button4').removeAttr("disabled");
                            $('#QCB1_Button4').removeClass('ms-disabled');
                            $('#QCB1_Button4 span').removeClass('ms-disabled');

                            $('#QCB1_Button5').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
                            $('#QCB1_Button5').addClass('ms-disabled');
                            $('#QCB1_Button5 img').css('opacity', '0.3');

                            $('#QCB1_Button6').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
                            $('#QCB1_Button6').addClass('ms-disabled');
                            $('#QCB1_Button6 span').css('opacity', '0.3');

                        } else if (SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(new SP.ClientContext.get_current()).length === 1) {

                            $('#QCB1_Button4').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
                            $('#QCB1_Button4').addClass('ms-disabled');
                            $('#QCB1_Button4 span').addClass('ms-disabled');

                            $('#QCB1_Button5').removeAttr("disabled");
                            $('#QCB1_Button5').removeClass('ms-disabled');
                            $('#QCB1_Button5 img').css('opacity', '1.0');

                            $('#QCB1_Button6').removeAttr("disabled");
                            $('#QCB1_Button6').removeClass('ms-disabled');
                            $('#QCB1_Button6 span').css('opacity', '1.0');
                        }

                        else {
                            $('#QCB1_Button5').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
                            $('#QCB1_Button5').addClass('ms-disabled');
                            $('#QCB1_Button5 img').css('opacity', '0.3');

                            $('#QCB1_Button4').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
                            $('#QCB1_Button4').addClass('ms-disabled');
                            $('#QCB1_Button4 span').addClass('ms-disabled');

                            $('#QCB1_Button6').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
                            $('#QCB1_Button6').addClass('ms-disabled');
                            $('#QCB1_Button6 span').css('opacity', '0.3');
                        }

                    }
                };
            });


            observer.observe(input[0], { attributes: true });
        }


    }


};

(function () {
    var ctx = {};
    ctx.OnPostRender = SIMON.Library.PostRender;
    ctx.Templates = {};
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
})();
```